# Rsync fails due to Sudo timeout

Tags: macos, sudo, rsync

I am trying to run a lengthy Rsync (local machine only, no ssh, no lan or wan connects involved) but Sudo is timing out and the script fails. Total runtime of the command is about 20 mins. What is the recommend way to either lengthen the Sudo timeout or disable Sudo from that particular command only? I am the admin of this system but do not log in as root.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which command are you actually running, what error message do you get when it fails?

Answer (score 1):

How are you actually invoking the script? If you run a script like `sudo script.sh`, all commands inside the script are run as superuser and you should never have it time out. If you're running a script that has `sudo` commands inside it, then it could ask for a password more than once if it takes too long between `sudo` commands. The `sudo` timeout only applies to new invocations of the `sudo` command. If your case is the latter, you do have the option of using the command `sudo -v` in your script which will extend the timeout by its default value (normally 5 minutes, but see below for how to change it), but if everything inside needs superuser permissions anyways, it makes more sense to invoke the entire script with `sudo`.

If you do want to change the sudo time out, you need to edit the `sudoers` file:

1. Bring up the `sudoers` file:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
2. Find the line that starts with:

   ```
   Defaults    env_reset
   ```
3. Add a comma and the command `timestamp_timeout=minutes` to the end
   (replace minutes with the number of minutes desired, 0 will always
   ask for a password, a negative number will never time out -
   *dangerous*):

   ```
   Defaults    env_reset,timestamp_timeout=10
   ```
4. Save and close the file.